# How to increase performance in Sequelize with node.js when there are nested tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables that are in a many-to-many relationship. In Sequelize, we can use the `separate:true` option to define a one-to-many relationship between a model and the join table. However, is there any way to improve the performance of many-to-many relationships in Sequelize?

Sample Table structure

- User
- Project
- UserProject(junction table)

`separate:true` functionality didn't work as I'm using belongsToMany().

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use lazy loading in this case and remove `include` option with `many-to-many` association.